# jQuery AJAX with multiple URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I'm using jQuery to load the images before displaying them. The problem is that I don't know how many images are going to be loaded. The page loads the image paths from a XML file. I'm using this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'images/BYLINE/1.png',
    dataType: "image/png",
    success: function(data) {
        alert('psil');
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

Comment: that is not a very clever choice of name for the `XMLHttpRequest` object as it hides the native `XMLHttpRequest` constructor within your callback. You can always access the native constructor as `window.XMLHttpRequest`, but you might want to reconsider renaming that parameter to `request` or something to avoid the naming conflict.

Comment: Thank you! Fixed. I haven't paid attention on it. :)

Answer (score 0):

is there any good reason for using jquery for this? you could simply use the good old technique for preloading images with javascript like this:

```
new Image().src = "images/BYLINE/1.png";
```

Comment: Is there anyway to have an callback when all images are loaded?